# Home page of asp.net mvc 5 application returning an xml style error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

for some time now the asp.net mvc 5 I have been working on is returning

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Message>
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://jobatease.local.com/'.
</Message>
<MessageDetail>
No action was found on the controller 'CommonApi' that matches the request.
</MessageDetail>
</Error>
```

This started one day when the current open file in my visual studio was *'CommonApiController'* ***a Webapi Controller*** as I set the start action of the site to current page, since then every time I build and start the project, It will show me the above xml error. So am wondering what to do so as to make it start displaying the main home page again. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ignore that message about style information (that’s just your browser showing you a note that this is just a raw XML document). The actual error is in the XML document: *“No action was found on the controller 'CommonApi' that matches the request.”*

Comment: right cick the project in the Solution Explorer and choose Properties. Make sure "Start Up Object" is  "(Not Set)". when you run the project you can choose the project in the Solution Explorer before running it.

Comment: Hi @montewhizdoh, the "Start Up Object" is already set to "Not Set"

Comment: did you try to choose the project in the Solution Explorer before running it?  make sure its highlighted. (Click on the top level of the project)